# Smarty Caching - how to force it?

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I'm assigning values to Smarty variables before loading the template file. Is there a way to tell Smarty to never cache the values of a particular variable? In some cases, like in search results, I don't want Smarty caching the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty3:  {$myvar nocache}  or surround the block with {nocache}{/nocache} tags.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.tpl

Comment: Is it possible to tell Smarty not to cache a variable when it's being assigned? Currently, I'm using the `nocache` tags -- but I'm having to surround a huge chunk of markup with them; not sure if this optimized caching. I'm not sure how to use the `nocache` parameter. For example, would I have to specify it every time I reference a particular variable? What if the variable is an array and I'm accessing an element in the array, do I put the parameter then?